# Flutter null safety: Error: A value must be explicitly returned from a non-void function

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
  Future<void> saveEverything() {

    _formKeyForDeposit.currentState?.save();

    Navigator.of(this.context).pop(true);
    return;
  }
```

This^ is throwing the error:

> A value must be explicitly returned from a non-void function.

I've tried returning void, I've tried `return true`, I've tried returning `Future<void>`, I've tried returning the Navigator.pop line.

There is an answer on Stackoverflow, but that doesn't work with enforced null safety, this function wants something returned despite being void. I don't understand it.

It won't compile, I'd love some clarity on what drives the issue, and a solution.

Comment: If the function isn't asynchronous, so you doesn't need to return a Future. Have you tried remove the Future?

Comment: Your function is *not* a `void` function.  Its return type is `Future<void>`, which is not the same thing.  Either you must return a `Future` (which is easiest by marking your function as `async`) or you must change your function's return value to `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see none of the called functions are async, so there is nothing you could `await`. This means that your function isn't asynchronous either and there is no need to use `Future` as a return type. `void` should work fine:

```
void saveEverything() {
    _formKeyForDeposit.currentState?.save();

    Navigator.of(this.context).pop(true);
}
```

Edit: To  specifically answer:

> this function wants something returned despite being void

The return type isn't `void`, it is a `Future` with a generic type of `void` . [`Future`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) is a normal class and thus your method expects an object of type `Future` to be returned. The `void` here is defining what type the value of a successfully resolved `Future` should have.

Comment: Cheers Puelo, yes I must have had some asyncs activities in the function once but refactored it at some point. Problem solved, thankyou! x Sam

Answer (score -1):

like this

```
Future<void> saveEverything() async {

_formKeyForDeposit.currentState?.save();

Navigator.of(this.context).pop(true);
```

}